# Trying to use chromedriver but get Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'log_file'"

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have code of this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

And the error occurs at the last line : driver = webdriver.Chrome()
It says this :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Edison/Desktop/untitled folder/huamai_jacket1.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    log_path=service_log_path)
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 42, in __init__
    start_error_message="Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home")
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.port = utils.free_port()
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 36, in free_port
    free_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 0))
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'log_file'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x1049a93d0>> ignored
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Edison/Desktop/untitled folder/huamai_jacket1.py"]
[dir: /Users/Edison/Desktop/untitled folder]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Happens this morning and the thing is right after this happens, sometimes when i access website even like google.com, the ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID page shows up often and i need to keep refreshing to get the page back to the regular site.

Is this because that the driver.Chrome() does not include the PATH of Chromedriver location? I used my script for a week before today though and everything worked perfectly. 
Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

So if you do not pass a path as a part of the "webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')" is will search along the PATH environment variable to find it. So first thing I would do is verify where my chromedriver is. If it is not in $PATH then you can put it in usr/bin and try running again. Or you can pass the path to your chromedriver executable in the .Chrome().

Comment: Is there anyway I can find the path/to/chromedriver at all please?

Comment: Sure! It will be where you downloaded it to. It will be a file called "chomedriver". So on windows you can use the search in the bottom left. On Mac and Linix the file browser has a search in it. So search for the file, find where you have it installed, and then you'll want to copy that path.